# Where is kernel information logged?

Tags: kernel, log

On my development computer I compiled a kernel module that I want to use on an Ubuntu system. It's a simple test module for now that just printk's a message.

On my development computer I can test that this works by `cat /var/log/messages`

On my Ubuntu computer I `insmod`ed the .ko and tried this, but there is no `/var/log/messages`. A google search told me that this had been renamed to `/var/log/syslog`, but looking in `/var/log` that does not seem to exist either. Why do I not have a log?

What I do see is the following:

```
Xorg.0.log
Xorg.0.log.old
apt
dmesg
dmesg.0
dmesg.1.gz
dmesg.2.gz
dmesg.3.gz
dmesg.4.gz
dpkg.log
dpkg.lob.1
dpkg.log.2.gz
lastlog
lightdm
pm-powersave.log
pm-powersave.log.1
pm-powersave.log.2.gz
pm-powersave.log.3.gz
pm-powersave.log.4.gz
samba
udev
unattended-upgrades
```

Comment: dmesg does have the printk, so that should work for me, thanks. Are there any differences I should be aware of between dmesg and messages?

Comment: Which release ?

Comment: Always assume latest release if not told :+

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/var/log/messages` is not used in Ubuntu (it got removed around Natty). We use `/var/log/syslog` for that. Everything logged to 'messages' back then was also logged into 'syslog' so we got rid of one of them.

I do have a syslog and a kern.log in `/var/log/`. I would expect the last one to hold anything kernel related.

There is a better method: the `journald` daemon has all what has been logged.

---

You can list kernel messages with:

```
$ journalctl -f _TRANSPORT=kernel
```

That should show you anything related to the kernel and you can grep the results if need be. But there is a lot of [options](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html) to refine your results (see the link or `journalctl --help`).

Other examples (from the link):

Without arguments, all collected logs are shown unfiltered:

```
journalctl
```

With one match specified, all entries with a field matching the expression are shown:

journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=avahi-daemon.service

If two different fields are matched, only entries matching both expressions at the same time are shown:

```
journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=avahi-daemon.service _PID=28097
```

If two matches refer to the same field, all entries matching either expression are shown:

```
journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=avahi-daemon.service _SYSTEMD_UNIT=dbus.service
```

If the separator "+" is used, two expressions may be combined in a logical OR. The following will show all messages from the Avahi service process with the PID 28097 plus all messages from the D-Bus service (from any of its processes):

```
 journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=avahi-daemon.service _PID=28097 + _SYSTEMD_UNIT=dbus.service
```

Show all logs generated by the D-Bus executable:

```
journalctl /usr/bin/dbus-daemon
```

Show all kernel logs from previous boot:

```
journalctl -k -b -1
```

Show a live log display from a system service apache.service:

```
journalctl -f -u apache
```